# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unrecognized property type: org.hibernate.type.BagType

Tags: java, mongodb, hibernate, hql, hibernate-ogm

I am trying to run following hql but getting `Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unrecognized property type: org.hibernate.type.BagType(org.model.Test.groups)` error.

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Test t " +
                    " JOIN FETCH t.groups g " +
                    " where t.id=:id" +
                    " and g.value.name= :name ")
                    .setString("id", id);
                    .setString("name", name);

List<Test> tList = query.list();
```

This one also gives the same error;

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Test t " +
                        " JOIN FETCH t.groups g " +
                        " JOIN FETCH g.value v " +
                        " where t.id=:id" +
                        " and v.name= :name ")
                        .setString("id", id);
                        .setString("name", name);

@Entity
@Table
public class Test {
    ...
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Group> groups;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table
public class Group {
    ...        
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "value")
    private Value value;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table
public class Value {
    ...
    @Column(name="name", nullable=false)
    private String name;
    ...
}
```

If i just run the following hql, i am getting the column values for all test, group and value tables without any problem.

```
Query q = session.createQuery("from Test t where t.id= :id")
                 .setString("id", id);
```

below is the full error stack trace;

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unrecognized property type: org.hibernate.type.BagType(org.model.Test.groups)
org.hibernate.ogm.query.parsing.impl.ParserPropertyHelper.getPropertyType(ParserPropertyHelper.java:104)
org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.query.parsing.impl.MongoDBPropertyHelper.getPropertyType(MongoDBPropertyHelper.java:48)
org.hibernate.ogm.query.parsing.impl.ParserPropertyHelper.convertToPropertyType(ParserPropertyHelper.java:48)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.spi.SingleEntityQueryRendererDelegate.parameterValue(SingleEntityQueryRendererDelegate.java:465)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.spi.SingleEntityQueryRendererDelegate.addComparisonPredicate(SingleEntityQueryRendererDelegate.java:305)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.spi.SingleEntityQueryRendererDelegate.predicateEquals(SingleEntityQueryRendererDelegate.java:284)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.render.QueryRenderer.predicate(QueryRenderer.java:5238)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.render.QueryRenderer.searchCondition(QueryRenderer.java:4912)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.render.QueryRenderer.searchCondition(QueryRenderer.java:4848)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.render.QueryRenderer.whereClause(QueryRenderer.java:2376)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.render.QueryRenderer.querySpec(QueryRenderer.java:2229)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.render.QueryRenderer.queryExpression(QueryRenderer.java:2132)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.render.QueryRenderer.queryStatement(QueryRenderer.java:1771)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.render.QueryRenderer.queryStatementSet(QueryRenderer.java:1684)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.render.QueryRenderer.statement(QueryRenderer.java:680)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.spi.QueryRendererProcessor.process(QueryRendererProcessor.java:51)
org.hibernate.hql.QueryParser.parseQuery(QueryParser.java:82)
org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.query.parsing.impl.MongoDBBasedQueryParserService.parseQuery(MongoDBBasedQueryParserService.java:40)
org.hibernate.ogm.query.impl.OgmQueryTranslator.getQuery(OgmQueryTranslator.java:169)
org.hibernate.ogm.query.impl.OgmQueryTranslator.getLoader(OgmQueryTranslator.java:134)
org.hibernate.ogm.query.impl.OgmQueryTranslator.list(OgmQueryTranslator.java:128)
org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1339)
org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87)
```

Comment: Is there code available for `Value` also?

Comment: @pirho  value table added to the post.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate OGM does not currently support JP-QL queries with JOIN on *-to-many associations: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/ogm/reference/en-US/html_single/#_using_jp_ql

Comment: I thought it was for 'hibernate search' and if you scroll down a little bit, it says 'Inner JOIN on an embedded association: works as expected with Neo4j and MongoDB; doesn’t work if your datastore provider implements JP-QL queries using Hibernate Search.' I tried INNER JOIN as well but no luck. After all, do you have any suggestion rather than fetching ids first than fetching entities related to those ids?

Comment: "embedded collection" is the key word, yours is not an embedded collection. I cannot think of any solution except for using native queries.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot say if this is the cause of your specific error especially cause there is only partial code from entites. But check this (because it complains about `Group`)

You seem to be after birectional mapping between `Test`<>`Group`, there is `@OneToMany` annotation and  `List<Group> groups` on `Test`.
How is `Group` mapped to `Test`? There is no `mappedBy` attribute or similar.

You should have something like:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="test")
private List<Group> groups;
```

on `Test` side. On `Group` side then you should hava a field like:

```
@ManyToOne
private Test test;
```

Maybe you have but not in the provided snippet.

Comment: I did not have those mappings since i am fetching one way. Still i added and tried and got the same error.

Comment: Did you test with a clean db? Without using @JoinColumn there might be  join table and stuff related to that in entities. Join table could be also mixing things originally but just a guess.

Comment: yes, it was actually working with SQL but once i converted it to HQL(which i have to) i started getting this error. Also, as i mentioned in the post, i don't have any problem fetching the sub-entities when i just fetch the test table data